# Tomcat 7 - Google Oauth2 - ClassNotFoundException - Java - Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I am trying to get offline access to my google calendar.
This question has been answered before here:
[Offline Access to google calendar using java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14393518/offline-access-to-google-calendar-using-java)
but for some reason I always get an ClassNotFoundException, when trying to authenticate.

I am running the application locally on an Apache Tomcat 7 Server and use Eclipse Mars. I installed the following APIs via the Google API ManagerPlugin:

- Google OAuth2 API v2
- (Google OAuth API v1) The plugin tells me, that v2 is preferred
- Google Calendar API

Usually I copy external jar-files to the *WEB-INF/lib* folder and to the *Tomcat/lib* folder but I guess the plugin does this for me right? All API's are listed on my JavaBuildPath.

If I run the same functions as *Java Application* it works, so something must be wrong with the Tomcat settings.

Did anyone have such an issue before and can help me? 
Thanks in advance.

Servlet (Credentials removed):

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());
    this.authenticate(request, response);
}


 public void authenticate(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {

        String client_id                = "";
        String redirect_uri             = "";
        String scope                    = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar";
        String client_secret            = "";
        List <String> scopes;
        HttpTransport transport         = new NetHttpTransport();
        JsonFactory jsonFactory         = new JacksonFactory();

        scopes = new LinkedList<String>();
        scopes.add(scope);
        GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(transport, jsonFactory, client_id, client_secret, scopes).build();
        GoogleAuthorizationCodeRequestUrl url = flow.newAuthorizationUrl();
        url.setRedirectUri(redirect_uri);
        url.setApprovalPrompt("force");
        url.setAccessType("offline");
        String authorize_url = url.build();
        response.sendRedirect(authorize_url);
    }
```

Console:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow$Builder
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1854)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1703)
at net.meetme.CalendarServlet.authenticate(CalendarServlet.java:88)
at net.meetme.CalendarServlet.doGet(CalendarServlet.java:42)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: What plugin? You're still going to need to deploy your application and its dependencies into tomcat.

Comment: The plugin is not going to to anything. The usual packaging of libraries in the war file should still be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your fast replies. 
I deployed all the jar-files to my WEB-INF/lib.

The mistake was that I also added all  the jar-files to the Java Build Path. 
You just need to remove these jar- files from the build path and it works.